# Running Angular project shows error as angular-in-memory-web-api

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

My **observerable** and **subscribe** class looks like below

**Observable**

[image]

**Subscribe**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

Comment: Are you using **angular-inmemory-web-api**? You may use it with any incorrect way. This [doc](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-inmemory-web-api/) may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing `@angular/http` package.

You can add it with :

```
npm install @angular/http
```

or

```
yarn @angular/http
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that you have installed the @angular/http in package.json file. 
if not then please install it by
`npm install @angular/http`

Always import the HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule after the HttpClientModule to ensure that the in-memory backend provider supersedes the Angular version.

and also follow the instruction given in the module introduction [angular-in-memory-web-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-in-memory-web-api)